# How to change default taxonomy for CPT only (not posts)

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I am trying to change the labels of the default category and tags taxonomies for a CPT only. When trying with the code pasted below it works, but it also changes the labels for the default post type.

```
function sm_add_portfolio_post_type()
{    
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    $wp_taxonomies['category']->label = 'Industry';
}
add_action('init', 'sm_add_portfolio_post_type');
```

[image: Taxonomy changed for default post type]
[image: Taxonomy changed for CPT]

Comment: This is not possible. If you intend to have `category` and `tag` taxonomies shared across built-in post types and custom post types, the label will remain the same. You may be able to change the label in the admin menu for your CPT, but not most anywhere else.

Comment: You should register new taxonomies for your post type, not attempt to rename the core taxonomies.